# Hex String to Byte array conversion java

Tags: java, arrays, string, mifare

I know this question is asked a lot of times but please hear me out.

Previously I have tried following methods to convert hex string to byte array.

say my keyA = "D14E2C5A5B5F", I use byte[] of this key to authenticate a mifare card

First Approach:

`byte[] ka = new BigInteger(keyA, 16).toByteArray();`

(With this approach using `ka` as key authenticates few cards and fails in few cards)

Second Approach:

```
byte[] ka = hexStringToByteArray(keyA);
public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

(With this approach using `ka` as key authenticates few cards, but success rate is more than first approach and fails in few cards).

Am I missing anything?
Is there any better way to convert hex string to byte array in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/hexStringToByteArray.htm

Comment: I have already tried this method, waiting for results from client. That is the reason I havent mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the leading `0` values created by `BigInteger`.

```
public void test() {
    test("D14E2C5A5B5F");
    test("00D14E2C5A5B5F");
    test("614E2C5A5B5F");
    test("00614E2C5A5B5F");
}

private void test(String s) {
    byte[] ka = new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray();
    byte[] kb = hexStringToByteArray(s);
    if (!Arrays.equals(ka, kb)) {
        System.out.println(s + ":" + Arrays.toString(ka) + " != " + Arrays.toString(kb));
    }
}

public byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    byte[] data = new byte[s.length()/2];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        data[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i*2), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i*2 + 1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

prints

> D14E2C5A5B5F:[0, -47, 78, 44, 90, 91, 95] != [-47, 78, 44, 90, 91, 95]
>
> 00614E2C5A5B5F:[97, 78, 44, 90, 91, 95] != [0, 97, 78, 44, 90, 91, 95]

See the extra leading `0`s.

Also, your `hexStringToByteArray` is **assuming** an even number of hex digits - this may be an issue.

Something like this should be correct. It ensure the `byte[]` is always the right length whatever the length of the string. You may wish to add an exception for when the string is too long.

```
public byte[] asKey(String hex, int bytes) {
    // Make sure the byte [] is always the correct length.
    byte[] key = new byte[bytes];
    // Using i as the distance from the END of the string.
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length() && (i / 2) < bytes; i++) {
        // Pull out the hex value of the character.
        int nybble = Character.digit(hex.charAt(hex.length() - 1 - i), 16);
        if ((i & 1) != 0) {
            // When i is odd we shift left 4.
            nybble = nybble << 4;
        }
        // Use OR to avoid sign issues.
        key[bytes - 1 - (i / 2)] |= (byte) nybble;
    }
    return key;
}
```

Comment: [Note the BigInteger behavior is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--) "Returns ... two's-complement representation ... contain[ing] ... at least one sign bit". Another option (also assuming even length in hexits) is [javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      int index = i * 2;
      int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
      b[i] = (byte) v;
    }
    return b;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
public static byte[] hexToByteData(String hex)
{
    byte[] convertedByteArray = new byte[hex.length()/2];
    int count  = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < hex.length() -1; i += 2 )
    {
        String output;
        output = hex.substring(i, (i + 2));
        int decimal = (int)(Integer.parseInt(output, 16));
        convertedByteArray[count] =  (byte)(decimal & 0xFF);
        count ++;
    }
    return convertedByteArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that showed the best performance...

```
    public static byte[] hex2bytes(String str) {
        if( str == null || str.length() == 0 )
            return null;

        byte[] hex = new byte[str.length() / 2];
        int tmp1, tmp2;

        for(int i=0; i < hex.length; i++) {
            tmp1 = str.charAt(i*2);
            tmp2 = str.charAt(i*2+1);
            hex[i] = (byte)( (tmp1 < 0x41 ? (tmp1 & 0x0F) << 4 : ((tmp1 & 0x0F) + 9) << 4)
                    | (tmp2 < 0x41 ? tmp2 & 0x0F : (tmp2 & 0x0F) + 9) );
        }

        return hex;
    }
```

Comment: "best performance" comparing to what?

Comment: @Emil  I tested the time it takes to convert a specific string 100 million times with various sources posted here.